# Save search results, new results in a new tab?

Tags: eclipse, search, ide

Many times when changing code, need to search for something, see one of the results in detail, search for something new based on the first result. see that, then go back to the first search result list and similarly process the 2nd find.

But the first search result list is gone due to the 2nd search.

Love to be able to save it/ make next search result appear in a new tab. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Eclipse Search view has a "Show Previous Searches" button in the upper-right section of the toolbar that preserves the last 10 searches (you can configure this number):

[image]